# How to cache minipanels

Tags: 7, panels, caching

I use minipanels in specific regions of pages (such as the main menu region) and they generally conain content that stays the same. How can I cache these minipanels?

Is the block caching system independent from the minipanels? I am not sure about that, since minipanels also show in the blocks configuration admin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache mini panels from mini panels UI settings. 
Go to the mini panel content edition page.

You have then 2 choices. Above in global mini panel display settings or per panel content piece : in its wheel settings at the bottom...